# Vue Google Place Autocomplete-how can I make the selected value display?

Tags: vuejs2, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I am implementing the [component](https://github.com/actengage/vue-place-autocomplete) like this:

```
<place-autocomplete-field
       v-model="field"
       name="field"
       label="Address lookup"
       :api-key="api_key.api_key"
       placeholder="Start typing here"
       @autocomplete-select="onPlaceInput"
>
</place-autocomplete-field>
...
        data() {
            return {
                api_key,
                field: null            
            };
...
```

While the @autocomplete-select event fires fine, and delivers the selected value, the value displayed in the component's input field does not update on selecting from the place options. All that is in the input field is whatever was typed in there. This is not how it works in the demo on Github. Can anyone spot what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: I just made it work directly with the google maps api and it's really awesome! no need to use external plugins. I am writing an article on it. will update soon!

Comment: https://medium.com/@siddhartharora02/places-autocomplete-service-by-google-maps-api-vue-js-js-client-side-202b7fd7baf0